# Mysql subquery not recognizing the subquery join table field

Tags: mysql, subquery, group-concatenation

I have a three tables. The main table is the journeydata and next table is the alarm tables. The primary key for journeydata is journeydataID and its available as key in the alarm tables. Next in the alarm table there is a fenceID which is a primary key of another table that is fence table. Below I am trying to run a subquery example.What I am trying to do is join all the alarm for a particular journeydataID if it exist into a single string. But I keep getting error #1054 - Unknown column 'alarmgroup.journeydataID' in 'on clause'. Next my task I want to show is a alarm has a fence name value. Example if there is a relevant value of a alarmName with fenceName show as alarmName(fenceName).

```
SELECT journeydata.dateTime,
alarmDetails
FROM 
journeydata
LEFT JOIN
    ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(alarmType.alarmName) AS alarmDetails 
      FROM alarm     
      JOIN alarmType
      ON alarm.alarmTypeID = alarmType.alarmTypeID
      LEFT JOIN fence
      ON alarm.fenceID=fence.fenceID
      WHERE alarm.associateID=6
      GROUP BY alarm.journeydataID
    ) AS alarmgroup
    ON journeydata.journeydataID=alarmgroup.journeydataID

WHERe journeydata.associateID=6
```

Comment: Please do not update a question with answers. I have rolled it back.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ sorry for that cause I was thinking to make easier for voltaire to assist further.

Comment: Thank you.  If the problem is solved, you can accept the answer that helped you. If the problem is not solved, you can edit the question and add more details below the existing text. Just don't correct the existing code, as it makes the answer look irrelevant.

Comment: If the problem is solved but you now face a new problem (after fixing this one), you can accept the answer and post a new question.

Comment: No I have added further problem in the first time itself the questioned asked.You can see it here "Next my task I want to show is a alarm has a fence name value. Example if there is a relevant value of a alarmName with fenceName show as alarmName(fenceName)."

Comment: Is `fencename` a column in `alarm` or `fence` table? I suppose it is in fence. And how do you want to show it? With `GROUP_CONCAT()` as the alarm name?

Comment: I think you want `GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(fence.fenceName, alarmType.alarmName))` but not sure.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ so I got delay on this fencename is a column from fence table. Yes your group concat coalesce and the different with using the if statement in it which is more efficient

Comment: @ypercube I found a bug with COALESCE it works only when the fence name is not null else everything is return as null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your derived table is missing the extra field it is looking for try this:

```
SELECT journeydata.dateTime,
alarmDetails
FROM 
journeydata
LEFT JOIN
    ( SELECT 
         GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT(
              IF(fence.fenceName IS NULL, alarmType.alarmName, 
                   CONCAT(alarmType.alarmName, 
                        '(',fence.fenceName,')'))
         )) AS alarmDetails,
         alarm.journeydataID as journeydataID   -- <<< ADDED
      FROM alarm     
      JOIN alarmType
      ON alarm.alarmTypeID = alarmType.alarmTypeID
      LEFT JOIN fence
      ON alarm.fenceID=fence.fenceID
      WHERE alarm.associateID=6
      GROUP BY alarm.journeydataID
    ) AS alarmgroup
    ON journeydata.journeydataID=alarmgroup.journeydataID

WHERE journeydata.associateID=6
```

There might be more that needs fixing, but I would need a little time to look over the query and information you have provided.   Try this for now.

**EDIT:** *Added the (untested) distinct grouping and formatting of `alarmDetails` as requested.*

Comment: yes its working when I added this line  alarm.journeydataID as journeydataID you miss the extra D I added but why I need that not quite sure. How about the fenceName how to combine it with the alarmname if there is a fence name ?

Comment: I have updated my question with you answer but I have edited the this GROUP_CONCAT(alarmType.alarmName,fence.fenceName) AS alarmDetails, What I notice is that now only those alarm with which have matching fenceName appear others dont appear. What I want to do is that for those no fence name just show the alarmname but those which have fencename to show as alarmName(fenceName)

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ is right btw, Best to accept the answer and create a new question.  Keeps the original question and answer simple.   Also helps out us low-reputation guys climb the reputation ladder.

Comment: I liked @ypercubeᵀᴹ's suggestion of using `COALESCE()` instead of `IF()`, i.e. `COALESCE(CONCAT(alarmType.alarmName,'(',fence.fenceName,')'),
 alarmType.alarmName)`.  Had to swap around some stuff, but this works because `CONCAT()` of a NULL field returns NULL overall.

Comment: yes the coalesce seems to be working meanwhile I was trying the if else statement. Which is better and efficient ?

Comment: My co-workers would probably say the `IF()` is more readable, but I like the reduced repetition of the `COALESCE()`.  I think its down to who-ever likely to be reviewing and maintaining your code.   Best bet is to ask them.   Performance wise, you could try looking up how to use `BENCHMARK()`.

Comment: you are right if I did was more readable but I saw COALESCE is doing with even simpler solution with out the the need for the single ' quotes. I will try to google on the benchmark never used it before.

Comment: over to solve this solution is GROUP_CONCAT the only solution left right or is there any other alternative?

Comment: I found a bug with COALESCE it works only when the fence name is not null else everything is return as null.

Comment: If you are using `COALESCE(CONCAT(alarmType.alarmName,'(',fence.fenceName,')'), alarmType.alarmName)` it should work.  If `fenceName` is `NULL` then the `CONCAT()` evaluated to `NULL`, then the `COALESCE()` will use the second argument `alarmName` instead.   You will only get `NULL` overall if  `alarmName` is NULL, even if `fenceName` is `NOT NULL`.   You could try `COALESCE(CONCAT(COALESCE(alarmType.alarmName,''),'(',fence.fenceName,')`